# How to write to Standard Output using BufferedWriter

Tags: java

I am currently writing an application that produces several log files using BufferedWriter.  While debugging, however, I want to write to System.out instead of a file.  I figured I could change from:

```
log = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tokenizerLog));
```

to:

```
BufferedWriter log = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
log.write("Log output\n");
```

as opposed to:

```
System.out.println("log output")
```

The new `OutputStreamWriter` option has not been working though. How do I change just the Object inside the BufferedWriter constructor to redirect from a file to Standard out.  Because I have several log files I will be writing to, using System.out everywhere and changing the output to a file isn't really an option.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Your approach does work, you are just forgetting to flush the output:

```
try {    
  BufferedWriter log = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

  log.write("This will be printed on stdout!\n");
  log.flush();
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The both `OutputStreamWriter` and `PrintWriter` are `Writer` instances so you can just do something like:

```
BufferedWriter log;

Writer openForFile(String fileName) {
  if (fileName != null)
    return new PrintWriter(fileName);
  else
    return new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
}

log = new BufferedWriter(openForFile(null)); //stdout
log = new BufferedWriter(openForFile("mylog.log")); // using a file
```

or whatever, it is just to give you the idea..

Comment: I'm glad I found this answer. My `FileWriter` was frequently generating files which contained the entire written content except for the very last chunk, and if you hadn't prompted me to call `flush()` when the output was finished then I reckon I'd have been chasing this ghost around the machine for quite some time.

Comment: @Bobulous: I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you mention that this is for logging, you might want to look at using a logger library like log4j. It'll let you change the log destination (either log file or console) by making changes in configuration files only.

Comment: I have to agree with this advice. The [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) framework is excellent and efficient. You can leave all of your logging lines in place in production code, and then configure your development environment to actively log all messages with "debug" level and higher, and configure your production environment to actively log only messages with a "warn" or "error" level and higher, so that your production logs don't get clogged with information only of interest during development changes. Very powerful, and very easy to use.