# Redirecting FileOutputStream to console - Java

Tags: java, console

I'd like to rewrite and simply my code to cut down on the number of methods in a class that do exactly the same thing but either write to a file, or to a console so I can do things like:

```
PrintFlightSchedule(String aFileName); // prints to a file
PrintFlightSchedule(); // writes to console.
```

I've tried creating the following test method just to demonstrate what I'my trying to achieve, by defining an abstract OutputStream, then instantiating it as either a PrintStream, or console (via System.out):

```
public static void testOutputStream(String fileNm, String msg) {
    OutputStream os;
    if (fileNm.equals("") ) { // No file name provided, write to console
        os = System.out;
    }
    // File name provided, write to this file name
    else {
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(fileNm);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File not found " + fe.toString());
        }
    }
    // Use the output stream here - ideally println method?
    // os.println or write(6);
}
```

This is admittedly half-assed, but it gives you an idea what I'd like to achieve.

Is there a way in Java to define the output method (file or console) at run-time, so I can use the same methods to do either, at runtime? I guess a simple way would be to redirect the FileOutputStream to the console - is that possible?

Comment: Can't you just use [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/) or something similar instead of writing it yourself?

Comment: Why not just write a method that takes a OutputStream as the main parameter. You could keep the two other methods and simply pass them through this third method...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270410/java-output-console-error-message-to-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to create a method that simply takes a `OutputStream` and writes all the details to it...

Then you create some helper methods that simply call it with the appropriate stream...

```
public void printFlightSchedule(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    // Write...
}

public void printFlightSchedule(File file) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
        printFlightSchedule(fis);
    } finally {
        try {

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public void printFlightSchedule() throws IOException {
    printFlightSchedule(System.out);
}
```

You may also want to take look at the [Code Conventions for the Java Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)...It will make it easier for people to read and understand your code ;)

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer flup and bowmore: I'm getting the message - provide the writer I want to use as a parameter to the method which is logical from a design perspective. As you can see, I ain't no expert at Java design, but it's interesting that when you go back to the fundamentals of design with these things, you often get the answer!

Comment: I like your idea of reducing your code duplication, that's the right frame of mind to be working from. To that end, start with lowest common denominator (OutputStream) and work out from there

Answer (score 2):

Don't provide a filename String as a parameter, but a Writer.
Your method's signature becomes

```
void PrintFlightSchedule(Writer writer);
```

The code you show would be the bit that creates the Writer on startup depending on runtime parameters:

```
public static Writer createOutputWriter(String fileNm) {
    OutputStream os;
    if (fileNm.equals("") ) { // No file name provided, write to console
        os = System.out;
    }
    // File name provided, write to this file name
    else {
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(fileNm);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File not found " + fe.toString());
        }
    }
    return new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));
}
```

Don't forget to flush the writer after output.
[How to write to Standard Output using BufferedWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405078/how-to-write-to-standard-output-using-bufferedwriter)

Comment: Thanks flup - consistent with other's suggestions: pass the writer I want as a parameter. All the answers are good.

Answer (score 2):

`java.io.OutputStream` is already an abstraction of 'something you can write bytes to'. If your class interacts with an OutputStream and the clients of your class can choose what that OutputStream actually is (a file, the console, a null device, ...) then your class won't need to care about the type of OutpuStream is actually needed for a given context.

So instead of your class trying to do what it needs to do *and* create OutputStreams for its clients, let it just focus on its true responsibility and let clients provide the OutputStream they desire.

So keep only one constructor :

```
/**
 * Constructs a new instance that will print to the given OutputStream
 */
PrintFlightSchedule(OutputStream stream);
```

Comment: Thanks bowmore, the key is going back to 'focussing on its true responsibility' as you say.

Comment: Yep, simply honor the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a FileOutputStream with a FileDescriptor instead of a string.

> **public FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj)**
>
> Creates a file output stream to write to the specified file descriptor, which represents an existing connection to an actual file in the file system.
>
> First, if there is a security manager, its checkWrite method is called with the file descriptor fdObj argument as its argument.
>
> If fdObj is null then a NullPointerException is thrown.
>
> This constructor does not throw an exception if fdObj is invalid. However, if the methods are invoked on the resulting stream to attempt I/O on the stream, an IOException is thrown.

And default FileDescriptors are:

```
static FileDescriptor   err
A handle to the standard error stream.

static FileDescriptor   in
A handle to the standard input stream.

static FileDescriptor   out
A handle to the standard output stream.
```

So the equivalent should be:

```
public static void testOutputStream(String fileNm, String msg) {
    FileOutputStream os;
    if (fileNm.equals("") ) { // No file name provided, write to console
        os = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.out);
    }
    // File name provided, write to this file name
    else {
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(fileNm);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
            System.out.println("File not found " + fe.toString());
        }
    }
    // Use the output stream here - ideally println method?
    // os.println or write(6);
}
```